# Comparing Dataframe with different amount of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame A like this:

| CARD_NUMBER | TRANSACTION_AMOUNT | TERMINAL_ID | EXTERNAL_STAN | TRANSACTION_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 604861*********3947 | 40000 | Y6152114 | 686817 | 21/01/2021 09:53:41 |
| 440833******4229 | 200000 | Y6152114 | 686821 | 21/01/2021 10:04:05 |
| 425322******8727 | 200000 | Y6152114 | 686847 | 21/01/2021 12:06:25 |
| 406606******7268 | 300000 | Y6152114 | 207606 | 21/01/2021 15:16:33 |
| 425322******5923 | 300000 | Y6152114 | 683213 | 21/01/2021 16:25:04 |

And another data frame B which looks like this:

| MICROFILM_REF_NUMBER | LINKUP_CODE | REVERSAL_FLAG | MCC | TRANSACTION_AMOUNT | TRANSACTION_CURRENCY | TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_EXP | TRANSACTION_DATE | ISSUER_ID | ISSUER_ICA | ACQUIRER_ICA | CLEARING_BIN | ACQUIRER_BANK_CODE | MERCHANT_NUMBER | MERCHANT_COUNTRY_CODE | MERCHANT_CITY_NAME | MERCHANT_ACRONYM | OUTLET_NUMBER | TERMINAL_ID | MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_SIGN | ISSUER_BANK_CODE | CLIENT_CODE | CARD_NUMBER | EXPIRY_DATE | TRANSACTION_SIGN | BILLING_AMOUNT | BILLING_CURRENCY_EXP | NETWORK_CODE | SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT | SETTLEMENT_CURRENCY | SETTLEMENT_CURRENCY_EXP | FUNCTION_CODE | AUTHORIZATION_CODE | AUTHORIZATION_DATE | ACTION_CODE | REFERENCE_NUMBER | INTERNAL_STAN | EXTERNAL_STAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70000021024100188324015 | AUTH10401003 | N | 6011 | 509,47 | 978 | 2 | 26/01/2021 18:39 | 515880 |  | 12658 | 12658 | 000003 |  | 710 |  | CALENDAR GIRLS BOYS JOHANNESBURG ZA | 000045 | 000045 | C | ISS003 | 0360835902 | 5158800746440660 | 01/01/2021 | D | 509,47 | 2 | 02 | 509,47 | 978 | 2 | 205 | 407309 | 26/01/2021 17:55 | 000 | 407309407309 | 670676 | 407309 |
| 70000021024100188324320 | AUTH10401003 | N | 6011 | 3038,85 | 978 | 2 | 26/01/2021 17:59 | 515880 |  | 12658 | 12658 | 000003 |  | 710 |  | CALENDAR GIRLS BOYS JOHANNESBURG ZA | 000045 | 000045 | C | ISS003 | 0348497473 | 5158800034404519 | 01/01/2021 | D | 3038,85 | 2 | 02 | 3038,85 | 978 | 2 | 205 | 763004 | 26/01/2021 17:16 | 000 | 763004763004 | 456406 | 763004 |
| 70000021024100188324064 | AUTH10401003 | N | 6011 | 6762,29 | 978 | 2 | 26/01/2021 18:12 | 515880 |  | 12658 | 12658 | 000003 |  | 710 |  | CALENDAR GIRLS BOYS JOHANNESBURG ZA | 000045 | 000045 | C | ISS003 | 0390027716 | 5158800663287854 | 01/01/2021 | D | 6762,29 | 2 | 02 | 6762,29 | 978 | 2 | 205 | 001532 | 26/01/2021 17:29 | 000 | 001532001532 | 536033 | 001532 |
| 70000021024100188324130 | AUTH10401003 | N | 6011 | 431,87 | 978 | 2 | 26/01/2021 17:35 | 515880 |  | 12658 | 12658 | 000003 |  | 710 |  | CALENDAR GIRLS BOYS JOHANNESBURG ZA | 000045 | 000045 | C | ISS003 | 0360236142 | 5158800688202193 | 01/01/2021 | D | 431,87 | 2 | 02 | 431,87 | 978 | 2 | 205 | 258257 | 26/01/2021 16:52 | 000 | 258257258257 | 286480 | 258257 |

I want to add a column 'Match' to data frame A so that one of the rows that exist from data frame A exits in data frame B then 'Match' is True, otherwise, it is False.

I also want to generate a file with the number of rows that matched and the number of rows that didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to your problem is to use the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function offer by Pandas. If you're familiar with SQL, this is just like a table join. The `pd.merge` adds the columns from  df1 to df2 by checking where the two data frames match on the names of the columns. This can be accomplished using the following function :

```
df3=df1.merge(df2, on=['col1','col2','col3'], how='left', indicator='Match')
```

For example, if df1 was :

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ahmed | mobarki | 20000.0 |
| mourad | melodi | 96000.0 |
| adam | karimi | 25000.0 |
| fatima | barkaoui | 30000.0 |
| david | mahri | 40500.0 |
| said | melloki | 96400.0 |
| ayoube | sharfi | 36420.0 |
| john | salali | 97500.0 |
| hajar | mously | 52400.0 |

and df2 was defined as:

[image]

Perform  Left JOIN with an indicator.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['FIRST_NAME','LAST_NAME','salary'], how='left', indicator='Match')
```

setting `indicator=Match` adds a column to the merged DataFame named as `Match` where the value of each row can be one of three possible values: `left_only, right_only, or both`.

we are interested when Match is equal `both` , because it means that the observations merge key is found in both DataFrames (we will then convert the `both` to `True`, or else it will be `False`).

```
df3['Match'] = df3['Match'] == 'both'
```

The `df3` will look like this :

[image]

Now let's back to your dataframes A and B:

```
C=A.merge(B, on=['CARD_NUMBER','TRANSACTION_AMOUNT','TERMINAL_ID', 'EXTERNAL_STAN', 'TRANSACTION_DATE'], how='left', indicator='Match')

C['Match'] = C['Match'] == 'both'
# create a new column Match in dataframe A  and fill it from C
A["Match"] = C['Match']
```